# In the Spotlight

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm two words long and have one "u".
I love to move around.
I'm very much invisible,
Even when I am found.

I'm almost always in the light,
So rarely in the dark.
And even if I'm in your yard,
Your dog will never bark.

The bitter cold is not my friend,
So I stay far away.
While you can find me where it's warm,
I must be on my way.

You will not catch me going east.
It's not my cup of tea,
But I go north and west and south.
That's good enough for me.

I'm in the water every day,
When I'm not on the land.
The sharks and storms don't bother me
If they get out of hand.

Volcanoes, tsunamis, earthquakes-
They don't scare me away.
But if I see a crab or goat,
I'll go the other way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are the

> **[subsolar point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsolar_point)** on Earth - the point where the Sun is directly overhead:
>
>   [image]

I'm two words long and have one "u". I love to move around. I'm very much invisible, Even when I am found.

> It  has one "u", moves  westward, completing a circuit of the Earth each day, and is not visible.

I'm almost always in the light, So rarely in the dark. And even if I'm in your yard, Your dog will never bark.

> The Sun is overhead so it's light, except during say Solar eclipses severe weather or volcanic eruptions.

The bitter cold is not my friend, So I stay far away. While you can find me where it's warm, I must be on my way.

> The subsolar point transverse the warm tropics daily, and is away from temperate regions.

You will not catch me going east. It's not my cup of tea, But I go north and west and south. That's good enough for me.

> It moves to the west, and to the north and south between the tropics over the course of a year.
>
>  [image]

I'm in the water every day, When I'm not on the land. The sharks and storms don't bother me, If they get out of hand.

> Each day it transverses land and oceans, unaffected by events on Earth.

Volcanoes, tsunamis, earthquakes- They don't scare me away. But if I see a crab or goat, I'll go the other way!

> When it touches the tropics of Cancer (crab) or Capricorn ( goat) it then veers towards the equator.

Comment: honored to have the riddle master get one of my riddles!

Answer (score 1):

You are

> The Sun

*I'm two words long and have one "u".
I love to move around.*

> The sun is always moving.

*I'm very much invisible,
Even when I am found.*

> You know where the sun is but can't look at it.

*I'm almost always in the light,
So rarely in the dark.*

> It's light where the sun is and dark where it's not.

*And even if I'm in your yard,
Your dog will never bark.*

> Dog's don't bark at the sun like they would an intruder.

*The bitter cold is not my friend,
So I stay far away.
While you can find me where it's warm,
I must be on my way.*

> It's warm where the sun shines and cold where it does not.

*You will not catch me going east.
It's not my cup of tea,
But I go north and west and south.
That's good enough for me.*

> The sun never goes east. It goes west every day. It goes north in the spring and south in the fall.

*I'm in the water every day,
When I'm not on the land.*

> Sets in the ocean and shines on land.

*The sharks and storms don't bother me
If they get out of hand.*

*Volcanoes, tsunamis, earthquakes-
They don't scare me away.*

> Earthly matters don't concern the sun.

*But if I see a crab or goat,
I'll go the other way!*

> The sun reverses direction at the tropics of Cancer and Capricorn.

Comment: +1 good try, cap. It's a decent fit, but the intended answer fits much better, I think